# PDE transformation to bessel differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I have the following ODE:

$$
r^2 \frac{f''}{f} + r \frac{f'}{f} - (kr)^2 = n^2
$$

And I would like to transform it into the modified bessel function for $z=kr$, so

$$
z^2 u'' + z u' - (z + \nu)u = 0
$$

I can't seem to find an appropriate transformation though. Any ideas?

Comment: Your equation is not a Bessel's equation $z^2 u'' + z u' - (z + \nu)u = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$r^2 \frac{f''}{f} + r \frac{f'}{f} - (kr)^2 = n^2$$
$$r^2 {f''} + r {f'} -( (kr)^2 + n^2)f=0$$
Substitute the variable $z=kr$:
$$z=kr \implies f'=\frac{df}{dr}=\frac{df}{dz}\frac{dz}{dr}=k\frac{df}{dz}$$
$$(rk)^2 {f''} + rk {f'} -( (kr)^2 + n^2)f=0$$
$$z^2 {f''} + z {f'} -( z^2 + n^2)f=0$$
And this is Bessel's modified equation. Not that $z^2 u'' + z u' - (z + \nu)u = 0$ is not a Bessel's equation. Maybe you made a typo ?